# Validate Param Types in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I've been looking all over the place and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. And just to double check, I'll ask you guys!

So I'm receiving `params` in a Rails controller. One `key, value` pair is `:status => true/false`. However, I find that when I try to post `status` as a string like

`:status => "THIS IS NOT A BOOLEAN"`

and create my object in my controller, the `:status` attribute of my object becomes `false`.

Therefore, is there any clean way in rails to validate that my `:status` corresponds to a boolean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This very strange method will to the trick

```
def is_boolean?(item)
  !!item == item
end

params[:status] = 'some string'
is_boolean?(params[:status])
# => false

params[:status] = true
is_boolean?(params[:status])
# => true
```

A slightly more intuitive version would be

```
def is_boolean?(item)
  item == false || item == true
end
```

Answer (score 3):

**Validation**

The [Rails way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) to do it is to validate in the model [(from the docs)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence):

```
#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :status, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }, message: "True / False Required!"
end
```

--

**MVC**

The reason for this is twofold:

> 1. **DRY**
> 2. **MVC**

If you want to keep your application DRY, you need to make sure you have only one reference to a validation throughout. Known as the ["Single Source Of Truth"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth), it means if you try and populate the model with other controllers / methods, you'll still invoke the same validation

Secondly, you need to consider the [MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). MVC is a core aspect of Rails, and means you have to use your controller to *collate* data only - pulling & compiling data in the model. This is also true for validations -- always make sure you keep your validations with the data (IE in the model)

Comment: what about when you need to fetch data?

Answer (score 1):

[The above @Iceman solution is good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100152/) if you are only doing it once place but you keep doing/repeating it in other places i suggest you to create `to_bool` method. i.e

```
class String
   def to_bool
    return true if self == true || self =~ (/(true|t|yes|y|1)$/i)
    return false if self == false || self.blank? || self =~ (/(false|f|no|n|0)$/i)
    raise ArgumentError.new("invalid value for Boolean: \"#{self}\"")
   end
end
```

and put this method in intializer or in library. And, you can simply do this

```
 Mymodel.new(status: params[:status].to_s.to_bool)
```

we are doing `to_s` just because to convert `nil` to `''` incase the `status` key isn't in `params` .